# Typescript static method in an abstract class to create an instance of self

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have

```
abstract class Foo {

}

class Bar1 extends Foo {
    constructor(someVar) { ... }
}

class Bar2 extends Foo {
    constructor(someVar) { ... }
}
```

I'd like to be able to create a static method that creates an instance of the final class (all constructors would have the same signature). So I want something like:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public static someAction(someVar) {
        const self = new this(someVar);
    }
}
```

But this cannot be done because `Foo` is abstract. Is this at all possible?

**UPDATE**

What if these classes have their own templates?

```
abstract class Foo<M> {

}

class Bar1 extends Foo<SomeModel> {...}
```

Now I want the `someAction` to know of the type `SomeModel`. I tried

```
public static someAction<A, T extends Foo<A>>(this: new (someVar: any) => T, someVar: any): T {
    const self = new this(someVar);
    return self;
  }
```

But unless I specifically do `Bar1.someAction<SomeModel>("blah")` the returned result is not available of the type of the data, i.e. `Bar1.someAction("blah")` doesn't know the data type

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to your updated question?

Comment: That's exactly the problem I have

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add an annotation for the `this` type of the static method. In this case `this` will refer to the class, and adding an annotation for the `this` parameter will make the static method visible only on classes that satisfy the constraint (in this case that a constructor with a single argument exists) and it will also help us extract the actual instance type of the class the method is invoked on :

```
abstract class Foo {
  public static someAction<T extends Foo>(this: new (someVar: any) => T, someVar: any): T {
    const self = new this(someVar);
    return self;
  }
}

class Bar1 extends Foo {

  constructor(someVar: any) {
    super();
  }
}

class Bar2 extends Foo {
  constructor(someVar: any) {
    super();
  }
}
let bar1 = Bar1.someAction(0) // of type Bar1
let bar2 = Bar2.someAction(0) // of type Bar2
```

Comment: This works great! I have another question, that I'll follow up with an update on this question. Would be fantastic if you know that too!

Comment: @Titian I am also experiencing an issue like Kousha mentioned in his update when extending a class with a generic. The type ends up being the base class and not the subclass. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But how do you access static properties from `Foo.someAction`. It now only knows `this` is a constructor. Declaring `this` as `extends typeof Foo` results instead in it saying abstract types are not constructable. Using an intersection seems to result in a lot of confusion regarding use of the constructor (I think due to how the generic is resolved).

Answer (score 1):

It think this problem should be managed with the [factory method pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method), and move the static method from the abstract class to the factory class.

So then you will have:

- **a factory class** with the static method responsible for creating the specific classes.
- **an abstract class** with the shared data, logic and the required abstract components to implement.
- **any extending classes** with implementation of the corresponding abstract properties and methods from the parent class.

So starting the same way as you had,

there is an abstract class with the shared data,

```js
abstract class Foo{
  constructor(someVar: any){
    ...
  }
}
```

and then there are some classes that extend the abstract class,

```js
class Bar1 extends Foo {
  constructor(someVar: any){
    super(someVar)
  }
}

class Bar2 extends Foo {
  constructor(someVar: any){
    super(someVar)
  }
}
```

to create each of those classes based on parameters, it's easy to have a factory with the creational logic:

```js
class BarFactory {
  public static barCreator(someVar: any): Bar1 | Bar2 {
    if(someVar.x === 'whatever'){
      return new Bar1(someVar)    
    } else {
      return new Bar2(someVar)  
    }
  }
}
```

At last you just get and use the instance using the factory.

```js
const bar = BarFactory.barCreator(someVar)
```

All abstract properties and methods are directly available.

But f you want to use specific methods or properties of the instantiated class then you will need to check the instance type.

```js
if (bar instanceof Bar1){
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some monkeying around I found a way to address your problem with generics.

The key is to ***not*** use a type variable in the extends constraint for the base class ***but*** to add the base class with the type variable as an intersection of the return type.

Use `any` instead of `T` here `static someAction<A, T extends Foo<any>>` ***and*** to add `& Foo<A>` on the return type.

```
abstract class Foo<M> {...}

class Bar1 extends Foo<SomeModel> {...}
```

```
public static someAction<A, T extends Foo<any>>(
    this: new (someVar: any) => T, someVar: any
): T & Foo<A> {
    return new this(someVar);
}
```

I was facing the exact same issue while trying to create a user defined type guard, and the same technique above also solve this problem.

```
public static isThisType<A, T extends Foo<any>>(
    this: new (...args: any) => T, value: unknown
): value is T & Foo<A> {
    return value instanceof this;
}
```